# Shape of a tensor

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

Suppose I have a variable that looks like this

```
[[[1., 2., 3.]], [[7., 8., 9.]]]
```

I have read this is a rank 3 tensor with shape `[2, 1, 3]`, but I don't understand where these numbers come from. In particular, what is the meaning of the 1 in this shape?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! I have changed the wording of your question and added tabs and quotes to improve the readability of the question. Not that it was that bad or anything, but just to help out. Good luck!

Comment: The notation is a way of showing row, column, and depth of your rank 3 tensor.  The "2" is because you have two elements in the first "row", i.e., two elements with [[stuff]] inside the outer [].  You have one column; each of those two entries only has one [] element inside it.  You have depth 3; each of the entries at the inner level has 3 elements in it.  If your tensor was [[[1, 2, 3], [4,5,6]], [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]] it would be a [2,2,3] tensor, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In order to find the shape of the tensor, we start from the outermost list and count the number of elements (or lists) inside. This count makes the first dimension. We then repeat this procedure for the inner lists and find the next dimensions of the tensor.

So in this example we start with the outermost list and we see it has two elements in it i.e. [1,2,3] and [7,8,9] therefore 2 in the shape, we then continue with the second last list which has one element in it i.e. the list [7,8,9] therefore that is where the 1 comes from. And then the third last list has 3 elements in it which explains the 3 in the shape. Therefore the shape is [2,1,3].

Comment: How is it that there is $1$ element in `[[7., 8., 9.]]`, & $3$ elements in `[[1., 2., 3.]]`?

Comment: the list [7.,8.,9.] is an element in itself.

Comment: So why isn't the list [1., 2., 3.] an element in itself?

Comment: Start with the outermost list and find the number of elements accordingly. @jbowman has given one more example. Hope that clears your doubt.